# Update large set of documents without knowing _id

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, elasticsearch-5

I would like up update a large set of documents in Elasticsearch at once.
One document looks like this:

```
{
  "_index": "vue_storefront_magento_1_1587559712",
  "_type": "product",
  "_id": "1123",
  "_version": 56,
  "_score": 7.7135754,
  "_source": {
    "sku": "381735",
    "score": "1"
  }            
  "fields": {
    "updated_at": [
      1589880769000
    ]
  },
  "highlight": {
    "type_id": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@configurable@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "sku": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@381735@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a JSON file that contains the data I want to update, there is no _id field, only an SKU. I want to use this JSON to create the request to ElasticSearch to update.

```
[
  { "sku": 381735, "score": 2 },
  { "sku": 381736, "score": 3 },
  { "sku": 381737, "score": 4 }
]
```

I would like to update all of the score fields based on the SKU field in the _source.
Is this possible? I already looked at the update by query API but can't figure it out :-/

Comment: How do you generate the JSON file with updates?

Comment: The JSON is from an external source. Maybe I should clarify a bit.